# JSON not able to access my object

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get the `thumbPaths` and `captions` from my JSON file.

JSON FILE:

```
"pictures": [

        {

            "title": "Animals", 
            "gallery": 

            [

                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                }

            ]

        },
        {

            "title": "Auroras", 
            "gallery": 

            [

                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                }

            ]

        },
        {

            "title": "Boats", 
            "gallery": 

            [

                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                },
                {
                    "path":"",
                    "thumbPath":"",
                    "caption":""
                }

            ]

        }
```

Im trying to save them to their own arrays so that I can handle getting images from the thumbPaths.
I am attempting to achieve this in an AsyncTask

```
public class getJSONObjects extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... URL) {
            // Access the JSONHandler for the URL
            Log.d(tag, "in background on getJSON Artist Gallery.");
            //initalize parser
            JSONParser jparse = new JSONParser();
            //call objects          
                JSONObject json = jparse.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                    pictures = new JSONArray(json.getString(TAG_PICTURES));
                    Log.d(tag, "after pictures");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // looping through All Pictures
                for(int i = 0; i < pictures.length(); i++){
                    Log.d(tag, "in loop for pictures");
                    Log.d(tag, "Index:" + i);
                    JSONObject c;
                    try {
                        c = pictures.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title2 = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        titles[i] = title2;
                        gallery = new JSONArray(c.getString(TAG_GALLERY));
                        Log.d(tag, "just got gallery array");
                        Log.d(tag, "before if statement");
                        Log.d(tag, "title:" + titles[i].toString());
                        if(title2 == titleTextView.getText().toString()){
                            Log.d(tag, "inside if statement");
                            for(int z = 0; z < gallery.length(); z++){
                                try {
                                    JSONObject d = gallery.getJSONObject(z);
                                    String thumbPath = d.getString(TAG_THUMBPATHS);
                                    String captions = d.getString(TAG_CAPTIONS);
                                    Log.d(tag, "thumbPath:" + thumbPath);
                                    Log.d(tag, "captions:" + captions);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

In the above I am trying to say that if the title is == to the title in the JSON array that it should only grab the thumbPaths and captions in the gallery under that title. That way I only grab what I need and nothing more.

How could I achieve getting the proper information from my JSON file?

Comment: I think you mean `title2.equals(titleTextView.getText().toString())` and not `title2 == ...`

Comment: Also, I think in your case you should look into using a streaming JSON api if you want to "only grab" what you need. That way you can create objects as you encounter them without having to store a large string in memory (this can cause a crash on some devices). It's a bit of work, but efficient memory wise. I've used [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) in the past for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a JSON `value` one needs to access them using the corresponding `key` .

In this case the structure is a JSON object that has a mixture of arrays and keys. So according to the structure given the first `key` is `pictures`.

This is of type `array` whose first element holds two keys (`title` and `gallery`). We are interested in `gallery`. `gallery` is again the instance of an array (it is an array of objects).So to access the first element we use `[0]` for gallery to get the first object.

This object consist of 3 key value pairs. You can access them by their corresponding keys using `object[key]` to get a particular value.

For example

To access first instance of `thumbPaths` and `captions`

```
Object["pictures"][0]["gallery"][0]["thumbPath"]  // will give : ""
Object["pictures"][0]["gallery"][0]["caption"]    // will give : ""
```

and so on ..

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Could you possibly explain that a little more? Im still a little new with JSON parsing on Android.

Comment: Yep ill just add a bit

Comment: Np :).Does the explanation help @KeeanoMartin ?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to approach it this way!!

Comment: Yes i believe it would be much neater . Glad to be of help .

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the documentation of the json package [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).

Replace stuff like

```
gallery = new JSONArray(c.getString(TAG_GALLERY));
```

with

```
gallery = c. getJSONArray(TAG_GALLERY);
```

also, as mentioned before, use `equals()` and not `==` for string comparisons.